# Send Android App from Firebase App Distribution to Google Play Console Production directly

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console, firebase-app-distribution

I'm using Firebase App Distribution for sharing the App with testers. Now what I want is to send App directly in Google Play Console production when testers pass it, rather then I upload the app to Google Play Console. Is there any way ?

I tried to do so but didn't find the way.